# Reorganize csv data

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

I work in a school that has multiple data entry forms and formats and I am trying to find a way to automate one example of data duplication.

We put student report card grades in on one online system, but we also need to add almost the same data (in a different format) to a national education ministry portal. I have been able to get a CSV data dump of the report card grades, and I am trying to work out how to reorganize it into the format required for the education ministry.

The CSV data is organized as follows:

| Name | Skill | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name_1 | Skill_1 | Score_Skill_1 |
| Name_1 | Skill_2 | Score_Skill_2 |
| Name_1 | Skill_3 | Score_Skill_3 |
| Name_2 | Skill_1 | Score_Skill_1 |
| Name_2 | Skill_2 | Score_Skill_2 |
| Name_2 | Skill_3 | Score_Skill_3 |

But I need it to be organized like this:

| Name | Skill_1 | Skill_2 | Skill_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name_1 | Score_Skill_1 | Score_Skill_2 | Score_Skill_3 |
| Name_2 | Score_Skill_1 | Score_Skill_2 | Score_Skill_3 |

I've been trying to get my head around VLOOKUP, but I don't think it's the answer...  Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please clarify the data type of each column (Are the score text or numbers? The best is to use sample data that is representative of the real data, meaning same type similar length,...)

Comment: Thank you. The Names and Skill fields are text strings and the Skill_Scores are single digit numbers.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify that (as mentioned previously the best is to provide representative data)

Comment: OK - so I've just rediscovered Pivot Tables after many years of not dealing with so much data... Amazing, but I'm not there yet. Now I'm hoping I can find a way to automate the creation of individual pivot tables. I'll need separate tables for each class, and then for each subject within those classes. Feels like I'm making progress though!

Comment: And now I've found the filters. I think that's it...

Comment: Hi, Phillip. Looks like you've found your solution. Please consider posting an answer to your own question. It might just help someone else who is looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, Pivot Tables turned out to be the answer. They allowed me to manipulate and display the data exactly how I needed, and the filters allowed me to easily separate and present the data by class and subject. I didn't have to build any sort of complicated combination of VLOOKUP or anything else, as I had feared!

When setting up the pivot table, I had to specify which columns held the data for each section of the table (rows, columns, values). To start with, I was getting errors, but this was because the source data had too many entries. Using the filters to limit cases solved that problem as well.